# Can enricher be applied to specific sink via json configuration?

Tags: serilog, appsettings

Having following config:

```
    "Enrich": "SuperCoolEnricher",
    
    "WriteTo:File": {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {...},
    },

    "WriteTo:Seq": {
      "Name": "Seq",
      "Args": {...},
    }
```

all the sinks are enriched. I would like to enrich the `File` one only, is there something I could do in the json config? Like, e.g.:

```
    "WriteTo:File": {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {...},
      "Enrich": "SuperCoolEnricher",
    },

    "WriteTo:Seq": {
      "Name": "Seq",
      "Args": {...},
    }
```

(which is not working)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a concept of sub-loggers, which actually are usable for this:

```
    "WriteTo:FileLogger": {
      "Name": "Logger",
      "Args": {
        "configureLogger": {
          "WriteTo:File": {
            "Name": "File",
            "Args": {
              "path": "Test-.log",
              "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Debug"
            }
          },
          "Enrich:File": "SuperCoolEnricher"
        }
      }
    }
```